# Проблемы с расшифровкой

Tags: c#, шифрование

Использую шифрование Rijndael. Проблема следующая:
если зашифровать строку и тут же расшифровать, то все работает отлично,
а если зашифровать строку и записать в файл, а потом считать его и расшифровать то выдает ошибку
"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Заполнение неверно и не может быть удалено."
Сам класс шифровки:

```
public static class SymmetricEncryptionUtility
{
    private static bool _ProtectKey;
    private static string _AlgorithmName;
    public static string AlgorithmName
    {
        get { return _AlgorithmName; }
        set { _AlgorithmName = value; }
    }
    public static bool ProtectKey
    {
        get { return _ProtectKey; }
        set { _ProtectKey = value; }
    }

    public static void GenerateKey(string targetFile)
    {
        // Создать алгоритм
        SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
        Algorithm.GenerateKey();

        // Получить ключ
        byte[] Key = Algorithm.Key;

        if (ProtectKey)
        {
            // Использовать DPAPI для шифрования ключа
            Key = ProtectedData.Protect(
                Key, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        }

        // Сохранить ключ в файле 
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            fs.Write(Key, 0, Key.Length);
        }
    }

    public static void ReadKey(SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, string keyFile)
    {
        byte[] Key;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(keyFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Key = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(Key, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        }

        if (ProtectKey)
            algorithm.Key = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Key, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
        else
            algorithm.Key = Key;
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptData(string data, string keyFile)
    {
        // Преобразовать строку data в байтовый массив
        byte[] ClearData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        // Создать алгоритм шифрования
        SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
        ReadKey(Algorithm, keyFile);

        // Зашифровать информацию
        MemoryStream Target = new MemoryStream();

        // Сгенерировать случайный вектор инициализации (IV)
        // для использования с алгоритмом
        Algorithm.GenerateIV();
        Target.Write(Algorithm.IV, 0, Algorithm.IV.Length);

        // Зашифровать реальные данные
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(Target, Algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(ClearData, 0, ClearData.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Вернуть зашифрованный поток данных в виде байтового массива

        return Target.ToArray();
    }

    public static string DecryptData(byte[] data, string keyFile)
    {
        // Создать алгоритм
        SymmetricAlgorithm Algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(AlgorithmName);
        ReadKey(Algorithm, keyFile);

        // Расшифровать информацию
        MemoryStream Target = new MemoryStream();

        // Прочитать вектор инициализации (IV)
        // и инициализировать им алгоритм
        int ReadPos = 0;
        byte[] IV = new byte[Algorithm.IV.Length];
        Array.Copy(data, IV, IV.Length);
        Algorithm.IV = IV;
        ReadPos += Algorithm.IV.Length;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(Target, Algorithm.CreateDecryptor(),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(data, ReadPos, data.Length - ReadPos);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock(); /////////////// ОШИБКА ////////////////////

        // Получить байты из потока в памяти и преобразовать их в текст
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Target.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Вот так записываю в файл

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(Account ac in login.allAccounts)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", ac.Name, ac.Password, ac.Folder));
        }

        byte[] data = SymmetricEncryptionUtility.EncryptData(sb.ToString(), login.keyFileName);
        File.WriteAllBytes("./users/users.dat", data);
```

Потом читаю с файла

```
byte []data = File.ReadAllBytes("./users/users.dat");
            string decr = SymmetricEncryptionUtility.DecryptData(data, keyFileName); //// Ошибка!!!
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема...

Comment: Пробовали алгоритму задавать свойство `Padding`?

Comment: Пробовал задавать только None.
Но тогда ничего не расшифровало

Comment: Вот попробовал все варианты Padding. Не помогает. Ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

У меня все работает. Данная ошибка возникает если секретный ключ задан неверно.
Обратите внимание на параметр **login.keyFileName** при записи, при чтении уже **keyFileName**, возможно, ошибка именно здесь.